# twisted critical unhandled error on scrapy tutorial

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to learn scrapy, using scrapy tutorial: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

So I ran "scrapy crawl dmoz" command and got this error:

```
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-07-14 16:11:02 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':     'tu
torial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME':   'tutorial'}

2015-07-14 16:11:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsol
e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-07-14 16:11:06 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-07-14 16:11:07 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

I'm using windows 7 and python 2.7. Anybody knows what's the problem? How could I fix that?

EDIT: My spider file code is:

```
# This package will contain the spiders of your Scrapy project
#
# Please refer to the documentation for information on how to create and manage
# your spiders.
import scrapy


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
     start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/computers/programming/languages/python/books/",
    "http://www.dmoz.org/computer/programming/languages/python/resources/"
]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

items.py code:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

pip list:

- bootstrap-admin (0.3.3)
- cffi (1.1.2)
- characteristic (14.3.0)
- cryptography (0.9.3)
- cssselect (0.9.1)
- Django (1.7.7)
- django-auth-ldap (1.2.4)
- django-debug-toolbar (1.3.0)
- django-mssql (1.6.2)
- django-pyodbc (0.2.6)
- django-pyodbc-azure (1.2.2)
- django-redator (0.2.3)
- django-reversion (1.8.5)
- django-summernote (0.6.0)
- django-windows-tools (0.1.1)
- django-wysiwyg-redactor (0.4.3.2)
- enum34 (1.0.4)
- ez-setup (0.9)
- flup (1.0.2)
- idna (2.0)
- ipaddress (1.0.13)
- iso8601 (0.1.4)
- logging (0.4.9.6)
- lxml (3.4.4)
- mechanize (0.2.5)
- MySQL-python (1.2.4)
- pbr (0.10.8)
- Pillow (2.7.0)
- pip (7.1.0)
- pyasn1 (0.1.8)
- pyasn1-modules (0.0.6)
- pycparser (2.14)
- pymongo (2.6)
- pyodbc (3.0.7)
- pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
- pypm (1.4.3)
- python-ldap (2.4.18)
- pythonselect (1.3)
- pywin32 (218.3)
- queuelib (1.2.2)
- Scrapy (1.0.1)
- selenium (2.44.0)
- service-identity (14.0.0)
- setuptools (18.0.1)
- six (1.9.0)
- sqlparse (0.1.15)
- stevedore (1.3.0)
- Twisted (15.2.1)
- virtualenv (1.11.6)
- virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
- virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)
- virtualenvwrapper-powershell (12.7.8)
- w3lib (1.11.0)
- xlrd (0.9.2)
- zope.interface (4.1.2)

Thx for the attention and sry for my poor English, isn't my native language.

Comment: Please show the code of your spider file.

Comment: I updated the question with the spider code, Frank. I try to copy and paste the tutorial code and typing by myself, both generated the same error. Ty for your attention.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Is this the complete content of the file? I had to add `import scrapy` at the beginning of the file and fix the indentation and your error did not pop up. Please post exactly the content of your spider file - small differences matter (and can even be the cause for the error)

Comment: My bad, updated with the entire code. Anyway if you just add "import scrapy" and fix the identention, do you think that could be any installation missing?

Comment: The error looks not like related to missing installation. My suspicion was the `item` definition. Did you edit already the `items.py` like the tutorial suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I just paste the entire items.py code at the question

Comment: Just tested on `Windows 7`, `python 2.7` machine and made the tutorial steps. Works like a charm. Maybe you could add the output of `pip list` to your question too see if anything is different. And maybe you can try to start over in a complete new directory!?

Comment: Add pip list,and tried with a  new directory, unfortunately same error =/

Comment: Puh - looks ok to me. I've no more ideas - anybody else some ideas what to check?

Comment: Frank, ty very much for your attention and your will to help. After a pywin32 reinstall my scrapy is working. I hope one day to be so good as you =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm beginning to learn scrapy as well and encounter the same question with yours.
After struggling with it for an afternoon, finally I found it's due to the pywin32 module only download without install.
You can try input the command below in the cmd to finish the pywin32 module install and try crawl again:

python python27\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install

I hope it will help!

Comment: Wow I tried this and cmd returns that there is no directory file.  So I opened the file folder and I noticed that pywin32_post install doesn't exist although pip list says that pywin32 is installed , this could indicate a problem. I will try reinstall^^

Comment: Yeaaaaaah. It was a pywin32 install problem, now  I can crawl o/. Ty for your attention

Comment: As a tip, @ViniciusdeCastro, I'd highly recommend you look into using `virtualenv` with Python, and keep each project in it's own environment.  It will help troubleshoot problems like this, and eliminate version conflicts between different projects you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **You are missing pywin32!**

The other answers are basically right, but not 100% correct. pywin32 is not a pip install! You must download the installer package from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

Make sure that you get the correct bit: 32 or 64. In my case I didn't realize I had the 32bit version of Python installed on my 64bit machine and the installer fails with "Cannot find Python 2.7 installation in registry". I had to install the 32bit version of pywin32. Once I did this, **scrapy crawl site** worked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see what your doing with items as your writing to a file. But its the imports maybe. Try this if this does not work try, pip install pywin --update and pip install Twisted --update, that should reinstall any corrupted files.
Plus I dont know if it's Stack's problem but you had some misplaced identation.
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider

```
from {Projectname}.items import {Itemclass}
import scrapy


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/computers/programming/languages/python/books/",
    "http://www.dmoz.org/computer/programming/languages/python/resources/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Also In Items.py you have to import the Field item, which contains the Dictionary list. so in your items.py import this `from scrapy.item import Item, Field
`

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy crashes with: ImportError: No module named win32api

You need to install pywin32 because of this Twisted bug.