# Scrapy tutorial twisted error

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and only have a basic understanding of python.
Running into an error when running the Scrapy tutorial.
I have a Windows 7 OS, 64 bit and a 32 bit Python 2.7.12 installed
Steps I've taken so far

- Followed steps as per the installation page and set up a virtual environment 'scrapy'
- activated the virtual environment
- Installed scrapy (all the dependencies too seem to have installed fine, including pywin, the 32 bit version)
- Ran steps as per the tutorial page
- `scrapy startproject tutorial`
- created file `quotes_spider.py`, with the code given on the [tutorial page](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/intro/tutorial.html)
- From scrapy\Scripts\tutorial I ran `scrapy crawl quotes` and got the following error

  ```
  (scrapy) F:\My Projects\scrapy\Scripts\tutorial>scrapy crawl quotes
  2016-11-05 14:21:59 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.1 started (bot: tutorial)
  2016-11-05 14:21:59 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings:                                 {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'],         'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
  2016-11-05 14:21:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled         extensions:'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats','scrapy.extensions.telnet.Telne        tConsole', 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] Unhandled error in Deferred:
  2016-11-05 14:21:59 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
  2016-11-05 14:21:59 [twisted] CRITICAL:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py",         line 12 60, in _inlineCallbacks    result = g.send(result)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90,         in crawl six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 72,         in crawl self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 97,         in _create_engine return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line         68, in __init__ self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-        packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py"
  , line 88, in __init__ self.middleware =         DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line                 58, in from_crawler return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line         34, in from_settings mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line         44, in load_object mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in         import_module__import__(name)
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-        packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 23, in <module> from         scrapy.xlib.tx import ResponseFailed
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\xlib\tx\__init__.py",         line 3, in <module> from twisted.web import client
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line         42, in <module> from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint,         SSL4ClientEndpoint
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 36, in <module> from         twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py",         line 30, in <module> from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "f:\myproj~1\scrapy\lib\site-        packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module> import win32api
  ImportError: No module named win32api
  ```

This is quite similar to the error discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439540/twisted-critical-unhandled-error-on-scrapy-tutorial) but the solutions suggested don't seem to work out. pywin is installed in my global environment C:Python27\Lib\site-packages but it doesn't show up in my virtual environment. I'm not sure how to install it in my virtual env since the pywin executable file only seems to allow installation under C. Thanks in advance for your help!
My pip list in the virtual env is
attrs==16.2.0
cffi==1.8.3
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==1.5.2
cssselect==1.0.0
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.1
incremental==16.10.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
lxml==3.6.4
parsel==1.0.3
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pycparser==2.17
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
queuelib==1.4.2
Scrapy==1.2.1
service-identity==16.0.0
six==1.10.0
Twisted==16.5.0
w3lib==1.15.0
zope.interface==4.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're missing win32api, simply install it via pip:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: Hey any idea whether the win32api (installed via pypiwin32) and pywin32 i downloaded from sourceforge are essentially the same thing? So I won't have further errors? Just asking because pywin32 was noted as essential on the Scrapy installation page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CraigDsouza yup, it's essentially the same thing. `pypiwin32` is just how it's called on `pypi` (PYthon Package Index) from which you can download and build it using `pip` package management sytem.